# Bootstrap dropdown parent menu active class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, class, menu

Rookie here, searched for answer and can't discover what i am doing wrong.

My menu works fine in active class on "normal" menus, but I cannot find the solution to make the parent menu a "active" one.

![dropdown menu bootstrap][1]

The code:

```
<!-- /.abre dropdown -->
<li class="dropdown">
  <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">O Que Fazer</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/sem-sair-de-carro/">Sem Sair de Carro  <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>
    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/de-carro-a-menos-de-15-minutos/">De Carro a Menos de 15 Minutos </a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/usando-o-carro/">Usando O Carro </a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<!-- /fecha dropdown -->
```

What am I missing?

I tried the class="active" but no good:

```
<a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" class="active" href="#">O Que Fazer</a>
```

Maybe this is quite basic, but searched around for an answer and cannot find aby.

Much appreciated

Answer (score 15):

I know it has been 6 months since you posted this, but I have a solution for you :)

I have got this piece of mark up from the getbootstrap.com (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) and all you have to do is add the word 'active' in the `<li class="dropdown">` like the code below:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
       <!--<li class="dropdown">-->
       <li class="dropdown active">
           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Industries <span class="caret"></span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
               <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
           </ul>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I hope it is not too late!

Comment: helped me out, too (with bootstrap v3)

Comment: it helped me too with bootstrap v3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with the attribut : `role="menu"` on the `<ul>` element ?

```
<!-- /.abre dropdown -->
<li class="dropdown">
<a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">O Que Fazer</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/sem-sair-de-carro/">Sem Sair de Carro  <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/de-carro-a-menos-de-15-minutos/">De Carro a Menos de 15 Minutos </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/usando-o-carro/">Usando O Carro </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
<!-- /fecha dropdown -->
```

Comment: I can make the dropdown change color, but I cannot make the parent to change color while in "active". Here's a image: http://imgur.com/wUKrMKQ   . It has to be in the data-toggle="dropdown" part of menu, right?

Comment: <a data-toggle="dropdown"class="btn dropdown-toggle" href="#">
O Que Fazer
<span class="caret"></span>
</a>

Comment: That opens up a sign beside the "o que fazer" parent... but still not "activating" the parent menu when opening one of the dropdown menus.

Comment: Instead of a `<li class="dropdown">` try `<div class="btn-group">`. Normally btn-group CSS class have got a property "active"

Comment: Thanks, but no luck. That means there is no way to have a parent menu active with <li class="dropdown">?

Comment: I have the same problem, I wondering if any have solved it in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

By removing `data-toggle="dropdown"` solved the problem for me.